# php set_time_limit not working with mod_fcgid?

Tags: php, timeout, mod-fcgid

It seems [set_time_limit function call](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) has no effect when php is running with mod_fcgid (the default in webmin). Can someone tell me how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're editing `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini` and that after editing it, you restart php-cgi. The command for that should be `sudo /etc/init.d/php-fastcgi restart`

**Edit:**

To increase timelimit, you'll need to find `max_execution_time` in your php.ini. Default value is 30 seconds. **This is required if PHP is running in safe mode.**

To disable safe mode, search for `safe_mode` in php.ini and set it to off.

See [PHP Runtime Configuration page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) for more info on that.

Comment: Thanks Saso, perhaps I should have been clearer as I was thinking of the php function call set_time_limit, will clarify this

Comment: Added an edit, I assume you wanted to increase the max execution time? That should work.

Comment: Much appreciated for the extra info. I really would like to use set_time_limit so I am only increasing the time for one script instead of the entire server. So it is not possible to use it with fcgid?

Comment: Remembered another thing: check if php is running in safe mode - though safe mode was removed in PHP 5.4